# WPF - How to get a cell from a DataGridRow?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I have a data-bound DataGrid with alternating row background colors. I would like to color a cell differently based on the data it contains. I have tried the solution suggested by this thread

http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=51143

But,

DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild(row)

always returns null.

I am using

```
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

But VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount() of a DataGridRow always returns 0. I have verified that DataGridRow is not null and has been populated with data already. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

If you know your row and index of the cell you'd like to access, then here's how you can do it in code:

```
//here's usage
var cell = myDataGrid.GetCell(row, columnIndex);
if(cell != null)
    cell.Background = Brushes.Green;
```

DataGrid Extension:

```
public static class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid,  DataGridRow row, int columnIndex = 0)
    {
        if (row == null) return null;

        var presenter = row.FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>();
        if (presenter == null) return null;

        var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
        if (cell != null) return cell;

        // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
        grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[columnIndex]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: thats the real answer.

Comment: I am trying something like this but it does not seem to work. Can you check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584353/wpf-control-datagrid-cell-color-change

Comment: Its nice if you add following [methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25229554/2470362) to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

First thing first, don't do this in code-behind. You're fighting the framework with this way of doing things. WPF is designed differently; you have to think in terms of how the framework wants you to do things. In the case of WPF, it's XAML markup + converter classes.

You need two things to achieve what you want:

- Proper XAML markup to setup the style of the DataGrid
- An IValueConverter implementation to translate the value of the text into proper highlight color.

Here goes:

**XAML In Your Datagrid**

The first thing you want to do is define the XAML necessary to style your DataGrid cells. It looks like this:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Setters>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource dataGridCellConverter}}" />
        </Style.Setters>
      </Style>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

What this is doing is setting up a binding to the RelativeSource (the DataGridCell) and telling it to use the Content.Text of the cell as the value to pass to the Converter (dataGridCellConverter).

**IValueConverter**

The next thing you need is an IValueConverter implementation to actually determine the colors based on the text of the cell:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
namespace UserControls.Utility.Converters
{
  public class DataGridCellConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value == null) return Colors.White.ToString();

      if (value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("CMS")) return "LIME";

      return "ORANGE";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I'm just looking for the text "CMS" and coloring the background cell; if "CMS" doesn't exist, then it returns the orange color instead.

**Specify Resources**

Now, you need to add markup in your window/usercontrol to specify the converter as an appropriate resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:DataGridCellConverter x:Key="dataGridCellConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And that should do it! Good luck.

Comment: 'In the case of WPF, it's XAML markup + converter classes.' - this is very yours personal perception