# Access Datatemplate with name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got many `TabItem`s, but only one `DataGrid` in a `DataTemplate`.

Now I will access the `DataGrid`, because I want to change the content...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTabItem">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="_uiDataGrid"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="_uiTabControl" SelectionChanged="_uiTabControl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Name="_uiTabItembla1" Header="bla1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentTabItem}"/>
        <TabItem Name="_uiTabItembla2" Header="bla2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource  ResourceKey=ContentTabItem}"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I cant access with the name `_uiDataGrid`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the datagrid from the content presenters content template :

```
var contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(_uiTabControl);
var dt = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
var datagrid = DataTemplateName.FindName("_uiDataGrid", contentPresenter) 
as DataGrid;
```

For finding the visual child, refer the functions `FindVisualChildren()` and `FindVisualChild()` as mentioned in [this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229503/findvisualchild-reference-issue/25229554#25229554)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
       where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    foreach (childItem child in FindVisualChildren<childItem>(obj))
    {
        return child;
    }

    return null;
}
```